# Arduino IDE timeout error Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ide, arduino

I have already successfully installed Arduino IDE 1.8.5 on Ubuntu 16.04. Now, I am having trouble getting programs to upload from my PC. I have a Mega 2560, I am using Arduino IDE 1.8.5, on Ubuntu 16.04. I read and tried he suggestions from other questions on Ask Ubuntu, but all of those seem to be more about getting the program installed. I have tried multiple times, and I am sure I have followed the install instructions to the T, but there is something else still in the way. My specific problem and question is about the upload process, once a program has been written.

I installed Arduino IDE in my /home directory

I can see /dev/ttyACM0 in **Tools > Ports**, which is selected, and **Tools > Boards >** *Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560* is shown as the board.

The error I am getting is:

```
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

I already did `sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0`, `sudo usermod -a -G dialout icymike`, and `sudo adduser icymike tty` which fixed a different issue, but did not help my case.

I am pretty sure it is Ubuntu, because I installed and used Arduino IDE 1.8.5 with no problem on a Mac. I am not finding much online, outside of "grayed out Ports menu", and changing USB permissions. I think I am missing some key point.

Does anyone happen to have the specific combination of Arduino IDE 1.8.5, with Ubuntu 16.04? How did you get it to work? Should I mess with the **Programmer** options?

Comment: I had this issue a while ago........ but I don't remember how I fixed it lol

Comment: This is actually not a duplicate question, it is kind of frustrating that people are saying that it is. I dont think any of you read my question, because if you did, you would not be calling it a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you, I voted to re-open it